# What's the relation between `std::cout` and `std::ostream`?

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/oc8ezdTjx) below somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::ostream& os = std::cout;

    os << "thanks a lot" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since the aforementioned code snippet works well, it indicates that `std::cout` is derived from `std::ostream`. But I can't find any direct reference yet.

As per [the document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), which says that[emphasis mine]:

> The global objects std::cout and std::wcout ***control output to a stream buffer of implementation-defined type (derived from std::streambuf)***, associated with the standard C output stream stdout.

The above quotation says that `std::cout` controls ouput to a type which derived from `std::streambuf` other than `std::cout` derived from `std::streambuf`.

And I only find the declaration of `std::cout` in a file named `/usr/include/c++/7/iostream`:

```
  extern ostream cout;      /// Linked to standard output
```

I can't find the implementation of `std::cout`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the document", it sounds like you mean [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout). Which specifies right there that the declaration of `std::cout` is `extern std::ostream cout;`, which means that `std::cout` doesn't just derive from `std::ostream`, it _is_ a `std::ostream` object.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/input.output#lib:cout

Comment: @NathanPierson Sorry, I forgot to paste the link. Updated now.

Comment: Also, in your link right at the top it has `extern std::ostream cout;`, so you know `cout` is an `ostream` object

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for pointing out that. I have thought this question for about half an hour. I just realised that the  type of `std::cout` is `std::ostream` after I just posted this post and look the declaration again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ostream` is a class. `cout` is an instance of that class.

This is no different from `class Person {}; Person john;`. `Person` is the class, `john` is an instance of that class. The C++ standard library just happens to create an instance (`cout`) of this particular class (`ostream`) ahead of time, configured to write to the standard output stream.

The line `std::ostream& os = std::cout;` defines a new variable called `os`, which is of type `ostream&`, that is a reference to an `ostream`. It then makes it a reference to the already defined variable `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the aforementioned code snippet works well, it indicates that std::cout is derived from std::ostream.

Not quite. The code works because `std::cout` is a `std::ostream`. No inheritance needed to read and understand that code example.

> The above quotation says that `std::cout` controls ouput to a type which derived from `std::streambuf` other than `std::cout` derived from `std::streambuf`.

The quote is talking about details that you need not care about (unless you do care about them ;). The important part of `extern ostream cout;`  for this quesiton is `ostream cout;` which means `cout` is an instance of type `ostream` (and `extern` just indicates that it is only a declaration while the definition (of the instance) is elsewhere, [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10422034/4117728)).

Answer (score 0):

To help the readers of this post, see the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/677hbYao4) below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(std::cout).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(std::ostream).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
So
So
```

The output indicates that they are the same type.